# How do I retrieve my contacts from my google account to my phone!

Tags: google-account, google, google-contacts

So I saved all my contacts by selecting the google account instead of saving on the phone.

But I removed the accounts from the phone, and when i added back the accounts to the phone, i could not find most of the new numbers..

Please help!

Comment: So you Saved contacts to your google account. Then Deleted them from the phone... Then synched to google (deleting them from Google)... then tried to restore them? Is that the flow that happened?

Comment: @RossC OP wrote he *removed the **accounts** from the phone*, not the contacts. // Paul: Please [edit] your question and add some more details: What device are you using? What Android version is it running? Did anything else change on the device between removing and re-adding the account? May sound stupid, but just to be sure: Have you checked you've added the correct account – just in case you're having multiple accounts?

Comment: Also, the contact sync is not instantaneous. The synchronization (especially phone-to-cloud) happens once every 10-15 minutes. If you happen to remove the account before the next scheduled sync occurs, the newly added contacts may be lost.  You could force a manual sync via `Settings -> Accounts -> Google -> <your account> -> Menu -> Sync now`.

Answer (score 4):

As MemCtrl mentioned, go to http://contacts.google.com and see if your contacts (with the new numbers) are there. If not, you can restore them using "Restore contacts..." option (hit the "More..." button to see it), provided they weren't deleted more than 30 days ago.

Answer (score 0):

Go to contacts.google.com - see if you can find them there. If not, then I'm afraid you're out of luck.